# Why is it that $x^3-x-1=0$ has three solutions mod $l$ if and only if Tr$(\rho_K(\text{Frob}_l))=2$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Where $K$ is the splitting field of $x^3-x-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$,

$\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong S_3 \cong \langle\alpha, \beta | \alpha^3=1, \beta^2=1, \alpha\beta=\beta^2\alpha\rangle$

$\rho_K:\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})\to$ GL$_2(\mathbb{C})$ by $$\alpha \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 
-1 & 1\\
-1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}, \beta \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1\\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} $$

I'd also like to understand how $\rho_K(\text{Frob}_l)$ is defined, as Frob$_l$ is not an element of the Galois group. Apparently it should be a well defined conjugacy class in $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$, but it's not clear to me why this is the case.

Comment: Traces of conjugated matrices coincide

Comment: Is $l$ prime? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, $l$ is prime.

Comment: @AndreaMori Can't quite see how this helps, sorry.

Comment: the primes with three distinct roots are expressible as $l=u^2 + 23 v^2. \; \; \; \; \; \; $ $59, 101,...$  Just one of those things

Comment: oh, 23 itself has a repeated root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken,
Saying that $x^{3} - x - 1$ has 3 solutions mod l is equivalent to saying that the residue field of K at the prime l is just $\mathbb{F}_{l}$ since it is already a splitting field there then.
Then, since $Frob_{l}$ is defined on the level of the residual extension, asking for the extension to be trivial is equivalent to asking $Frob_{l}$ to be the identity.
But, when looking at the different matrixes you wrote above, $\alpha,\alpha^{2}, \beta,\alpha \beta, \beta \alpha$ have all traces different from 2, while the Identity matrix has trace 2; so that asking the trace to be the 2 corresponds to the vanishing of the residual extension mod l